# Increment counter ONLY once per item click

Tags: jquery

The code below basically increments a counter whenever an item with single class is clicked. There are many items with single class.  What I need to do which I cannot figure out is how to make the counter increment once even though a single item has been clicked multiple times.

```
var counter = parseInt($.trim($(".counter").html())); 
items.click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("single")) { 
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        //increment counter            
        $(".counter").html(++counter);

        //if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {               
        //    $(".counter").html(counter);
        // }
    }
    else { 
        return false;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? Per item you can basically only update the counter once? Why did you add `.stop()` by the way?

Comment: You already check if it has class single. Can't you check for it being selected and not increment in that case either?

Comment: well, stop is stopping animation applied to each single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove the class `single` from your code after you increment your counter, that should fix the problem.

But, you might need that class for other things, so here's another simple way we could handle it:

```
var counter = parseInt($.trim($(".counter").html())); 
items.click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("single") && !($(this).hasClass("selected"))) { 
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        //increment counter            
        $(".counter").html(++counter);
    }
});
```

Lastly, are you using [jQuery UI Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/)? If so, the `selected` class could be conflicting  with automatically generated code.

Comment: i know what remove class is for. stop() is actually there to stop animation applied to each single item. I have modified the code but removeClass does not answer the question, i'm afraid

Comment: It looks like we're going to need more code from around the bit you've posted, or a little more description of what you are trying to do. I'm happy to continue to try to help, though.

Comment: i tried to isolate the code for focus. basically, lets say there are 4 div elements with single class, if you click on all 4, the counter should be a maximum of 4. but with my current code, the counter continues to increment to infinity. Is that better?

Comment: My answer has been updated, hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Everything is still working? Can you mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to click only once

```
$('#first_name').one('click', function()
{
console.log('a')
});
```

Comment: i tried one function before closing the question, it does not work